# How to get data from two different table in cake php

Tags: cakephp-2.0

But it will give return same data from tab[1] only..
i want to get data from tab[1] and tab[0] distinctly

$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

$tab = $db->listSources();

```
        echo '<br>';
        $this->Form->useTable=$tab[1];
        print_r($this->Form->find(`all'));
        echo '<br>';
        $this->Form->use Table=$tab[0];
        print_r($this->Form->find('all'));
```

Comment: You have a space that shouldn't be there: `$this->Form->use Table=$tab[0];`. Unless that's just a typo in your question then I'm surprised that doesn't cause errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Model->useTable` at runtime does not work properly because once a model has been initialised, CakePHP caches the schema of the database-table.

To switch to another table and clear the cached schema, use `Model->setSource('tablename')`

Documentation; http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Model.html#1100-1125

Your example will then look like this;

```
echo '<br>';
$this->Form->setSource($tab[1]);
print_r($this->Form->find(`all'));
echo '<br>';
$this->Form->setSource($tab[0]);
print_r($this->Form->find('all'));
```

Also, please use `debug()` to output results for debugging in stead of `print_r()`. This will output the results properly formatted. (You'll need to set debug to 1 or higher inside your app/Config/core.php configuration for debug() to work)

**however**

Switching the sourcetable of a Model is generally bad practice and will only apply to very specific cases. I would *strongly* suggest to create a separate model for each database table.

Comment: thanks,,i want to make such a thing which will dynamically give table's data ,thats whay i have to do this...