# requestAction and useTable in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, behavior

I have a problem with the requestAction object of cakePHP.
I would like to retrieve the last 5 results of my Model but I use a view Table.

So in my action I put `$this->Model->useTable = 'models_view';`

but when I call my action by `$this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'models','action'=>'lastFive'));`,
cake use the default table whereas it should use my view table...

And also give me an error because I use conditions in fields which does'nt exist in my initial table (but exist in my view).

If anyone have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403655/how-to-get-data-from-two-different-table-in-cake-php/15421243#15421243 However, in many situations you don't have to use requestAction as this will give a lot of overhead. You can just load the model and get the results. If you're interested, I'll add some additional information

Comment: Reading your question again; is your model *actually* called **Model**? If so, this will *not* work. *Model* is a reserved name, because the Model-class already exists and is the 'base' class for all Models

Comment: thanks a lot thaJeztah! No, I renamed my model name by Model for this example. But your solution of changing the source is good. But finally, I've created a specifique action for my Home page and I've put my logic into, so I did'nt use requestAction anymore. But thank you a lot, it will be usefull for another uses.

Comment: Glad I could help! I will flag this question as a duplicate of the question I referred to. Not to offend you, just because it's probably 'cleaner' than to simply copy the same answer here :)

Comment: LOL, never mind. The other answer wasn't 'accepted' so, I'll copy it here so that this one can be marked 'answered'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `Model->useTable` at runtime does not work properly because once a model has been initialised, CakePHP caches the schema of the database-table.

To switch to another table and clear the cached schema, use

```
$this->MyModel->setSource('tablename');
```

This will clear and refresh the cached schema information in the model with the information of the 'new' table. 'tablename' can be either a 'table' or a database 'view'

Documentation; http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Model.html#1100-1125